# What is the best way to post to a Wordpress blog from a node app?

Tags: node.js, wordpress, authentication

I own a content writing company, and I'm currently trying to build an app that will allow my writers to post blogs to my client's stores. I want this app to work with Shopify and Wordpress sites/stores.

Shopify has a single-click authentication process that redirects a user to log in to their store and then returns a permanent token that is used to authenticate my app's requests to the site's API.

I'm trying to figure out how to do something similar for users with Wordpress sites. Do Wordpress sites have a REST API that can accept POST data to a blog? If so, what's the best way to get an access token/whatever authentication info I need?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, WordPress does have a REST API that is extendible.

Check out the handbook for the WP REST API:

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/